# Powershell script to get full path and get file version

Tags: powershell

My end goal here is to get all exe that are lower than version 1.0.0.0 and update those folders with new updated files by copying them to it.

there are multiple destinations where they reside, namely our terminal servers. lets use the below example.

```
$RDP1Path = "\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\"
$RDP2Path = "\\RDP02\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\"
$RDP3Path = "\\RDP03\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\"
$RDP4Path = "\\RDP04\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\"
```

There are 10 - 15 different folders in "Software" and each folder has the same exe name "Software.exe" but they are different for each client and not all clients are running the same version. We have an update for all clients that are running version 1.0.0.0 and we need to update them to version 1.0.0.1

Anyone running v 0.0.9.0 should not be updated.

Any ideas how i go about this?

Right now i can get a list of all exe's inside the folder but i cannot use the write-host somehow to read the file version of each

```
$GetFullPaths = get-childitem $RDP1Path-Recurse | where {$_.Name -eq "Software.exe"} | % {Write-Host $_.FullName}
```

This give me the following output:

```
\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\Client1\Software.exe
\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\Client2\Software.exe
\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\Client3\Software.exe
\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\Client4\Software.exe
\\RDP01\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software\Client5\Software.exe
```

How should I proceed ahead.

Comment: i haven't yet gone around to test it but i've marked it as an answer. as i am super busy with other items now and wont get time to test this for a few weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have permissions to do so and the `Software.exe` is not currently running, you should be able to do that with below code:

```
$serverNames     = 'RDP01','RDP02','RDP03','RDP04'   # an array of server names
$newSoftwareFile = 'D:\SoftwareNew\Software.exe'     # the full path and filename to the new version
$versionToUpdate = [version]'1.0.0.0'                # the version of the exe to be replaced

# loop through the servers list, find the exe with productversion 1.0.0.0
# and when found, copy the new file to that directory.
foreach($server in $serverNames) {
    $path = '\\{0}\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software' -f $server
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter 'Software.exe' -Recurse -File |
        Where-Object { $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw -eq $versionToUpdate } |
        ForEach-Object { 
            Write-Host "Updating '$($_.FullName)'"
            # you may need to first stop the process if software.exe is currently running
            # and after copying the new version start it up again...
            Copy-Item -Path $newSoftwareFile -Destination $_.DirectoryName -Force
        }
}
```

---

You can also opt for not having the code try and replace the file, but simply return a list of updatable paths.
In that case, do:

```
# loop through the servers list, find the exe with productversion 1.0.0.0
# and when found, output the file path and capture in variable $result
$result = foreach($server in $serverNames) {
    $path = '\\{0}\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software' -f $server
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter 'Software.exe' -Recurse -File |
        Where-Object { $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw -eq $versionToUpdate } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
}

# output on screen
$result

# or write to text file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\softwareToUpdate.txt'
```

---

If you only want a listing of all 'Software.exe' files together with their version numbers, use:

```
# loop through the servers list, find the exe and return FullName and versions
$result = foreach($server in $serverNames) {
    $path = '\\{0}\C$\Program Files (x86)\Software' -f $server
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File |
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = {$_.FullName}},
                  @{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersionRaw}},
                  @{Name = 'FileVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw}}
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or write to csv file
$result |Export-Csv -Path 'D:\softwareVersions.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Besides `ProductVersionRaw`, an exe file will also have a `FileVersionRaw` property. Both are `[version]` objects and they are not necessarily the same, so make sure you are using the correct verion.</sup>

Comment: Thank You for this, I will test and report back.